# Brotli for R is not compiling correctly

Tags: r, compression, brotli

I am trying to install the brotli package in R.  As usual, I run:
install.packages("brotli")

However, for some reason, the compilation seems to not be completing.  I have tried this now on two different systems (one on my Mac, the other on an EC2 instance).  Here are the errors:

```
wrapper.c:94:14: error: unknown type name 'R_CallMethodDef'

static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
             ^
wrapper.c:95:28: error: use of undeclared identifier 'DL_FUNC'
  {"R_brotli_compress",   (DL_FUNC) &R_brotli_compress,   3},
                           ^
wrapper.c:96:28: error: use of undeclared identifier 'DL_FUNC'
  {"R_brotli_decompress", (DL_FUNC) &R_brotli_decompress, 1},
                           ^
wrapper.c:100:20: error: unknown type name 'DllInfo'
void R_init_brotli(DllInfo *dll) {
                   ^
wrapper.c:101:3: warning: implicit declaration of function         'R_registerRoutines' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
  ^
wrapper.c:102:3: warning: implicit declaration of function     'R_useDynamicSymbols' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
  ^
2 warnings and 4 errors generated.
make: *** [wrapper.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘brotli’
* removing     ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/brotli’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/private/var/folders/6s/dkpknwzd4d51qm959wqxv7280000gn/T/RtmpHOPjwI/downloa    ded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("brotli") :
  installation of package ‘brotli’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm not as proficient in C as I probably should be, but I tried to reverse engineer it with no avail.  Am I missing something?  I also tried to install this with the dependencies option (dependencies = TRUE).  Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: What R version/compilers/etc. (`sessionInfo()`) ? You can check what compilers etc. CRAN check is using for `brotli` on different systems [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_flavors.html#r-release-osx-x86_64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems as thought, through some additional poking in the C code, that the solution was really simple.  I just didn't have r-development installed.  After installing on both my mac and my EC2, it now installs with no issue.  This is strange, since I would imagine that a decent R package should be able to be installed without the need of the development packages.  But maybe I'm too inexperienced in R package development to comment an opinion on the matter.  None-the-less, I hope this helps other less-experienced that are seeking to install the same package.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Depends what you call "decent". A package that does not require compilation should not need the development package. In addition, the binary versions of many packages available from CRAN for MacOS and Windows should not need the development package. But once you enter the realm of compilation, you will need the necessary tools (compilers, libraries with headers, ...).

Comment: not sure why brotli required it.  to my understanding, it is still relatively new (i think the first release was in 2016).  Maybe it's just a setting in my R that I'm missing.  As far as I know, though, installation of the development package fixed the issue.  I had tried looking for straight binary versions of the package, but had no success.

Comment: From https://cran.r-project.org/package=brotli we learn two things: First, the brotli package requires compilation. Second, binary versions for MacOS are available for R release (3.5) and R oldrelease (3.4). You are using R 3.3, which is to old for binary packages from CRAN.