# r package installation error "unknown type name ‘R_CallMethodDef’"

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm trying to install r package "sparsesvd" using `install.packages()`, but got error during compilation. Any help is highly appreciated!

> "unknown type name ‘R_CallMethodDef’"

I also tried `conda install -c r r-sparsesvd`; but got error.

> Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current channels:
>
> - r-sparsesvd
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/r/linux-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>
>   ...

I tried

`conda skeleton cran --recursive r-sparsesvd
conda build r-sparsesvd`.

While the 1st step was successful, the build failed.

> Execution halted 
>   Tests failed for r-sparsesvd-0.1_4-r341h96ca727_0.tar.bz2

Here is the sessionInfo. Due to project reason, I have to use R3.3

> R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>   Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C  [3]
>   LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8  [5]
>   LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8  [7]
>   LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C
>   LC_TELEPHONE=C [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] tools_3.3.2

Comment: Have you tried the one archived: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sparsesvd/

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But how would the archived one be different from the one chosen automatically by `install.packages()`?

Comment: There is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312369/brotli-for-r-is-not-compiling-correctly) related to the error

**unknown type name ‘R_CallMethodDef**

But the author did not give details on how to solve the problem. Could anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

This (once again) is not a problem with R, CRAN or its packages ...but apparently with Conda.  On my system there is strictly no problem with this *small* package with very few dependencies:

```
R> install.packages("sparsesvd")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/sparsesvd_0.1-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 29729 bytes (29 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 29 KB

* installing *source* package ‘sparsesvd’ ...
** package ‘sparsesvd’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe   -std=gnu99 -march=native -c las2.c -o las2.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe   -std=gnu99 -march=native -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe   -std=gnu99 -march=native -c svdlib.c -o svdlib.o
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe   -std=gnu99 -march=native -c svdutil.c -o svdutil.o
svdutil.c: In function ‘svd_readBinFloat’:
svdutil.c:265:5: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     y = *((float *) &x);
     ^
svdutil.c: In function ‘svd_writeBinFloat’:
svdutil.c:290:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
   int y = htonl(*((int *) &r));
   ^~~
gcc -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o sparsesvd.so las2.o main.o svdlib.o svdutil.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sparsesvd/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (sparsesvd)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpI3TPWj/downloaded_packages’
R>
```

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestion on how to resolve this problem in my machine?

Comment: Sorry, no. You _could_ try to narrow it down via simpler packages, simpler compilations, ...  And, as I mentioned, try to not use Conda.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That error **unknown type name ‘R_CallMethodDef** is from `install.packages`, not `conda`.

Comment: Of course it. Because it compiles then links and thereby gets a linking error because you seem to mixing incompatible systems.